# The impact of a distributed application configuration on node discovery via net_adm:ping/0

Tags: erlang, distributed, distributed-system

I am experiencing different behavior with respect to net_adm:ping/1 when being done in the context of a Distributed Application.

I have an application that pings a well-known node on start-up and in that way discovers all nodes in a mesh of connected nodes.

When I start this application on a single node (non-distributed configuration), the net_adm:ping/1 followed by a nodes/0 reports 4 other nodes (this is correct). The 4 nodes are on 2 different physical machines, so what is returned is the following n1@machine_1, n2@machine_2, n3@machine_2, n4@machine_1 (ip addresses are actually returned, not machine_x).

When part of a two-node distributed application, on the node where the application starts, the net_adm:ping/1 followed by a nodes/0 reports 2 nodes, one from each machine(n1@machine1, n2@machine2). A second call to nodes/0 after about a 750 ms delay results in the correct 5 nodes being found. Two of the three missing nodes are required for my application to work and so, not finding them, the application dies.

I am using R15B02

Is latency regarding the transitive node-discovery process known to be different when some of the nodes in the mesh are participating in distributed application configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The `kernel` application [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html) mentions the way to synchronize nodes in order to stop the boot phase until ready to move forward and everything is in place. Here are the options:

> `sync_nodes_mandatory = [NodeName]`
>
> Specifies which other nodes must be alive in order for this node to start properly. If some node in the list does not start within the specified time, this node will not start either. If this parameter is undefined, it defaults to [].
>
> `sync_nodes_optional = [NodeName]`
>
> Specifies which other nodes can be alive in order for this node to start properly. If some node in this list does not start within the specified time, this node starts anyway. If this parameter is undefined, it defaults to the empty list.

A file using them could look as follows:

```
[{kernel,
  [{sync_nodes_mandatory, [b@ferdmbp, c@ferdmbp]},
   {sync_nodes_timeout, 30000}]
}].
```

Starting the node `a@ferdmbp` by calling `erl -sname a -config config-file-above`. The downside of this approach is that each node needs its own config file.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I did. And it is in this scenario that I see the difference in the node discovery behavior.  It is as if, in the distributed application situation, a lot of latency appears when the application (one the primary node ) starts or does a take over

Comment: There is some synchronization work done between distributed application controllers for distributed applications. I'm not exactly sure how things work internally regarding the mesh connection setup, but I figure there could be some impact.

Comment: Yep, that's my thought too. I was hoping that someone could give me some information that would make this a little bit predictable so that I can figure out how to compensate. Thanks for your help/thoughts.

Comment: No problem. Sorry for misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Are you kidding me? I f@&kn love your site - it's helped me tremendously. I appreciate any attempt to help.